# How to make the touchpad work on Acer Travelmate P243?

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, acer

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit) on my laptop (Acer Travelmate P243) and didn't manage to make the touchpad work.

It is detected:

```
xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

It is working in Windows 7 setup.

It is active - at least the checkbox in dconf-editor: setting --> org --> gnome --> settings-daemon --> peripherals --> touchpad is set.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I accidentally found a workaround. Fn+F7 won't work after the OS booted. However, it will if it is activated just before logging in. Please make your system boot with authentication and have a try. (Posted on Jul 22 at 7:36)

Today I found that Ctrl+Fn+F7 makes the touchpad in function. The combination keys toggle the touchpad on and off. So no more restarting the laptop when forgot to activate the touchpad prior to logging in.